# Comparing the state variable with the local variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react state variable, I wanted to check if something changes out there then my **useEffect()** hook can sense that and *show* me the submit button visible. So for that I had the original const variable as it is, and I made the state copy of the same variable using **useState()**.

Eg:

```js
    const abc = {MONDAY:{OperatingHours: ["00:00", "23:59"], toggle: false}, TUESDAY:...};
    const[stateAbc, setStateAbc] = useState(MONDAY:{OperatingHours: ["00:00", "23:59"], toggle: false}, TUESDAY:...});
```

I wanted to compare the these two variable in my React component. If showButton is set as false I won't make the button visible else I will make it.

When I am making the state variable changes (like *OperatingHours*) back to initial states ["00:00", "23:59"] while running my application, I can't enter into this condition (abc === stateAbc) and the submit button is still visible:

```js
    const initialRender = useRef(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {
    if (initialRender.current) {
      initialRender.current = false;
    }
    if (abc === stateAbc) {
      setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);    // This condition is never meeting
    }
    if (abc !== stateAbc) {
      setSubmitButtonDisabled(false);
    }
  }, [stateAbc]);
```

Comment: You can simply use lodash library and use `isEqual()` function to compare these two objects. Like `isEqual(abc,stateAbc)`

Comment: Thanks, it helped in deep comparisons between the values :)

Comment: Also can I use isEqual in ternary comparison way ?:

```isEqual(abc, stateAbc) ?setSubmitButtonDisabled(true) : setSubmitButtonDisabled(false);```

Showing me the eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions, 

While this is working ```setSubmitButtonDisabled(
      isEqual(abc,stateAbc)
    );```

Comment: do it like this `setSubmitButtonDisabled(isEqual(abc, stateAbc))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing objects with `===` only gives true if the objects are the same :

```
const a = { name: "John Doe" };
const b = a;
console.log(a === b); // true
----
const a = { name: "John Doe" };
const b = { name: "John Doe" };
console.log(a === b); // false
```

Sometimes you see developers use `JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)` but it's not safe at all, the object properties are not always in the same order:

```
const a = { name: "John Doe", age: 30 };
const b = { age: 30, name: "John Doe" };
console.log(a, b) // { name: "John Doe", age: 30 } { age: 30, name: "John Doe" }
```

If you have simple objects to compare (all the values are primitive values), you can compare them by iterating through the properties :

```
let equals = true;
for (let key in a){
   if (a[key] !== b[key]) equals = false;
}
```

But if you have nested objects which is your case, the best way is to use an npm package for the comparison such as [deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal).